# Link between use case and functional requirement

Tags: requirements, use-case

I have a list of functional requirements

1. FR nr 1
2. FR nr 2
3. ...

And have a list of use cases that describe the requirement from the actors point of view. I mean `use case nr 1` describe `FR nr 1` and so on.. But do I need to create a link in the `use case` to the `FR`? Problem is that FR and use cases are located in different pages in Wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Use-cases are derived from functional requirements. It's not necessary to have a 1-1 correlation between a requirement and a use-case; actually in most situations a single use-case will be based on several requirements and a requirement may appear in several use-cases. The reason for this is that a use-case doesn't describe just any activity in the system but a high-level activity triggered by an external source. On the other hand, functional requirement usually describes internal or partial activity and yields a functional block inside use-case.

It's not necessary but it can be nice from documentation perspective to have links from use-cases to relevant requirements.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly necessary given the ease of doing this with a wiki I would say yes you should just do it.  It will enhance traceability.  On the usecase diagram I would include an attached note with the FR reference and in the usecase document use the identifier.